# Vite, monorepo with yarn workspace and SCSS

Tags: sass, vite, monorepo, yarn-workspaces

Have a monorepo with several packages that depend on a module `@carbon/styles`, a module that provides only SCSS files.

Because this is a common dependency, the package is hoisted to the root node_modules unless I specify `nmHoistingLimits: workspaces` in my root .yarnrc.yml.

Each of my packages have a TypeScript file that imports a local style.scss that has a line like this:

```scss
@use '@carbon/styles';
```

This causes an error during `vite build` for that line...

> Error: Can't find stylesheet to import.

Had thought vite would look for modules in the package's node_modules first, then look at the folder above and so on to the root of the monorepo. It seems to do this for modules that are JavaScript but not for SCSS.

While I can explicitly add an alias.resolve for `@carbon/styles` to my vite.config.ts or add `nmHoistingLimits: workspaces` to .yarnrc.yml, I am interested to know if this is expected behavior and whether there is a more global way to override the behavior so SCSS resolution works the same way as JavaScript.